# GTM doesn't recognize my dataLayer but console does?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

So I have a dataLayer created that works just fine when using the console in Chrome:

[image: The dataLayer in Chrome console.]

In Google Tag Manager, this dataLayer doesn't exist. Why?

The code I've used is below:

```
<script>

<?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $dataLayer = [];
    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
         $_product = $values['data']->post;
?>

<?php
         $dataLayer[] = [
    'itemUnitID' => $_product->ID,
              'itemUnitPrice' => get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true),
              'itemQuantity' => $values[quantity]


         ];

     }; 

?>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push(<?php echo json_encode($dataLayer); ?>);

</script>
```

So basically the code is shooting a dataLayer, but I can't use any of those values in Google Tag Manager as GTM doesn't even recognize the dataLayer in the first place. Why is that?

Comment: You need to push an `event` at the same time as those values, and then use that `event` as part of a trigger for the tag where those values are being used.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into how to push an event at the same time. I'm not that good at coding. Would be really helpful with some changes to the code above.

Comment: The dataLayer from the console looks odd to me, but maybe I'm just not familiar with Woo commerce. Usually, you should have the products objects nested under the `purchase` object, which itself is under an `ecommerce` object. The event can be pushed in at the same time when you are pushing all the other product details in. Here are couple of references: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases, and http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/ecommerce-tips-google-tag-manager/.