# How to push event at the same time I create an object/array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is what my array looks like:

[image]

It is not being recognized in Google Tag Manager. I have been told I need to be pushing an event at the same time as those values. But how?

I have tried everything!

This is my code:

```
<script>

<?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $dataLayer = [];
    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
         $_product = $values['data']->post;
?>

<?php
         $dataLayer[] = [
    'itemUnitID' => $_product->ID,
              'itemUnitPrice' => get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true),
              'itemQuantity' => $values[quantity]


         ];

     }; 

?>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push(<?php echo json_encode($dataLayer); ?>);

</script>
```

Ideally, this is how I would want my dataLayer to look like:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is identical to another question you asked, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137320/gtm-doesnt-recognize-my-datalayer-but-console-does. You should just stick to editing the original question rather than posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can start to create directly what you need in the end.

```
<?php
  //Init the array with default data.
  $dataLayer = [
     'checkout' => 'overview',
     'customer' => [], //I don't know what you will have here
     'product' => [], //At first we create an empty array and we will add here the products.
  ]

    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    //Get all products and go one by one.
    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
         $_product = $values['data']->post;
         //We will add a new product in $dataLayer product sub array
         $dataLayer['product'][] = [
              'sku' => $_product->ID,
              'unit_price' => get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true),
              'quantity' => $values[quantity],
              'category' => $values[category],  //Or how you can get the category name for a product.
              'name' => $values[name],  //Or how you can get the name of a product
              'parent_id' => $values[parent_id],   //or how you can get the parent_id of a product.

         ];

     }; 

?>
```

After that set dataLayer in `js` with `json_encode` the value from `php`

```
<script>
      window.dataLayer = <?php echo json_encode($dataLayer); ?>;
</script>
```